# Como retorno as listas de uma lista em ocaml?

Tags: lista, ocaml

Não sei como retorno as listas de uma lista na linguagem ocaml.

Por exemplo: queria que dando o `input` `[["Preto";"Branco"];["Amarelo";"Vermelho"]]` retornasse `["Preto";"Branco"]` e depois `["Amarelo";"Vermelho"]` numa função recursiva.